# Typesafe TypeORM exception mistakes managing

Tags: javascript, c

I need to create an software with NestJs and TypeORM the usage of MongoDB. Let's assume I even have an entity with two particular fields except the ID area

When I need to create a new module with a moduleName or displayName that already exists I'm getting the following exception errors As you can see it [here](https://www.ultimateknifekit.com). Maybe it will help you.
Does TypeORM expose premade exceptions? Is there an enum I ought to use? What would be a great approach to fetch the ones TypeORM database mistakes?

Comment: A link to ultimateknifekit.com, interesting. Seems sketchy. Not the knife kit, the link.

Comment: This is pretty scattered. It's hard to tell if this is even a real question. Although I'm not familiar with the tech you mention.